# Удалить все символы, кроме 'a' регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Короче, дается строка типа "aabbbbaaa". Надо удалить все, кроме 'a' и вернуть длину строки. Мое решиение не работает. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка или предложите более элегантный способ узнать количество символов 'a' в строке (цикл с полным переболом не пойдет)

```
s.replace("[^a]", "");
```

Comment: А почему не пойдёт? Самый простой, быстрый и элегантный способ, как на мой вкус.

На C# можно было бы ещё `s.Count(c => c == 'a')`.

Comment: @VladD, а codehunt.com считает иначе и за цикл дает одну звездюльку из трех.

Comment: @izobara: хотите понять, почему codehunt.com не правы? Попробуйте измерить производительность обоих решений.

Comment: @VladD, на шарпе за ваш код 3 звезды. На джаве за обычный цикл 1-а.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s.replaceAll("[^a]", "");
```

Comment: Что-то не работает...

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        s.replaceAll("[^a]", "");
        System.out.println(s);
 }

ввожу aaabbaaabbaaa, выводит aaabbaaabbaaa . JDK 7

Comment: @izobara: это потому, что вы забыли: строки в Java неизменяемы.

Comment: @VladD, точно, поправил. А как такое же провернуть с символом, передающимся в функцию (то есть, заранее неизвестным)?

Comment: @izobara: наверное, так:

    s.replaceAll("[^" + c.toString() + "]", "")

?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.replaceAll("([^a])+", "");
```

Comment: То же самое. https://ideone.com/inkpre

Comment: Вы забыли кусок `s = ` на 14 строке.